# There are too many api listener. Is there any way to organize it neatly?

Tags: android, api, kotlin

```
interface ApiListener {
    fun onApiVoidCallBack(type: Int, responseData: Response<Void>?)

    fun onApiGetFindPw(type: Int, responseData: Response<Void>?)

    fun onApiPutClientGroupCallBack(type: Int, responseData: Response<Void>?)

    fun onApiManagerCallBack(type: Int, responseData: Response<Manager>?)

    fun onApiAddGroupCallBack(type: Int, responseData: Response<AddGroup>?)

    fun onApiAddCustomerCallBack(type: Int, responseData: Response<AddCustomer>?)

    fun onApiAddDevicesCallBack(type: Int, responseData: Response<AddDevices>?)

    fun onApiDashBoardInfoCallBack(type: Int, responseData: Response<DashBoardInfo>?)

    fun onApiDashBoardGroupInfoCallBack(
        type: Int,
        responseData: Response<ArrayList<DashBoardGroupInfo>>?
    )

    fun onApiDashBoardGroupDetailCallBack(
        type: Int,
        responseData: Response<ArrayList<DashBoardGroupDetail>>?
    )
    fun onApiDevicesCallBack(
        type: Int,
        responseData: Response<ArrayList<DevicesList>>?
    )
    fun onApiPutClientsCallBack(type: Int, responseData: Response<Void>?)
    
    fun onApiPutClientsDeleteCallBack(type: Int, responseData: Response<Void>?)

    fun onApiDashBoardGroupDetailLogCallBack(
        type: Int,
        responseData: Response<ArrayList<ArrayList<DashBoardGroupDetailLog>>>?
    )
    fun onApiLogsCallBack(type: Int, responseData: Response<List<Logs>>?)
}
```

I'm a novice developer.

There are too many api listener.

Is there any way to organize it neatly?

This is my code.

I'm using the rest api

I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to make the code more efficient.

Comment: Why don't you just use two Generic method `#onSuccess(Response<T>)` and `#onError(e:Exception)`

Comment: Where are these methods overriden? At the very least, you can make an `interface ApiListener<in T>` and have a `fun callback(type: Int, responseData: Response<T>?)`. Please post more info on how your code is structured.

Comment: Use Kotlin co-routines or RxJava.

Comment: What does the `type: Int` represent?